# Magento filter for sort by Most reviews on category page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a requirement where I need to create a filter on catalog page for filtering products based on most reviews. I want to add it to Sort by filters on category product list page.

Help me guys please I am under a huge pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product collection for a particular category is fetched by this method:
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getProductCollection()

You will need to modify the above method and make a join with your review table so that this products collection now also has access to the number of views a product has.

[This might be a good starting point:](http://itssaurabhsworld.blogspot.in/2012/06/sort-products-by-popularity-count-in.html)

Responding to the comments:

The code in that post is working pretty perfectly for me except for the fact that I had to modify: getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() instead of getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/config.php

```
   /**
     * Retrieve Attributes Used for Sort by as array
     * key = code, value = name
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = array(
            'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
            'popularity' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Popularity')
        );
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

This is the query for the collection that is formed:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, count(review_id) AS `review` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '18'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `review` AS `t2` ON t2.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id and t2.entity_id = '1'  GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `review` asc
```

And it is working pretty smoothly for me.

Comment: I had implemented this already but it then messed up the pagination and results....

Comment: I don't think providing you with a complete solution for the said thing is within the scope of this site.I don't think that that code would mess up anything else apart from sort by reviews for you.

Comment: I have tested this already. It isn't doing what I am expecting.  The pagination stoped working and its just showing 1 results on the number count but there were about 837 products.

Comment: Is this for all types of sort filters or only the custom filter created for reviews? While I don't endorse that blog post completely but it would give you a good idea on how you could accomplish this. I don't think the code mentioned in the blog post should affect anything but the review filter.

Comment: Code written above doesn't just sort the products it returns just products with reviews and ignores all other products that are available in that category. Also it shows the wrong product count on the category toolbar on catalog page.

Comment: Have edited my answer with more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

copy

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php**

to
**app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php**

and add an index in toolbar list in `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()`

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = array(
            'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')

        );
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

to

```
 public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
        {
            $options = array(
                'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
                'mostview' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Most View'),
               'review' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__(' Review')

            );
            foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
                /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract */
                $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
            }

            return $options;
        }
```

copy

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php**

to

**app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php**

add new function sortBymostview for most view and sortByReview for review

```
public function sortBymostview($dir){
      $RecentviewSelect=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
            ->select()
            ->from('report_event',array('mycount'=>'COUNT(event_id)','product_id'=>'object_id'))
            ->where('report_event.event_type_id = 1')
            ->group('report_event.object_id');


        echo   $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('bs'=>$RecentviewSelect), 'bs.product_id = e.entity_id',
         array('mostview' => 'bs.mycount'))->order("mostview $dir"); 
}
```

and

```
public function sortByReview($dir){
      $RecentviewSelect=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
            ->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('review/review'),array('review_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'),'product_id'=>'entity_pk_value'))
            ->where("{$this->getTable('review/review')}.status_id = 1")
            ->group("{$this->getTable('review/review')}.entity_pk_value");


           $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('bs'=>$RecentviewSelect), 'bs.product_id = e.entity_id',
         array('review' => 'bs.review_count'))->order("review_count $dir"); 
}
```

and goto

copy

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php**

to

**app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php**

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());


    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
     if($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'mostview'){
         $this->_collection->sortBymostview($this->getCurrentDirection());
     }
     elseif($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'review'){
         $this->_collection->sortByReview($this->getCurrentDirection());

     }

    elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to show base on views. I want to show it based on reviews.